# Count with three different column in-between two tables in Power BI

Tags: if-statement, count, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a two tables are Data and Report.

**Data**

Data table contain the following three columns are Check, Supplier Status and Condition.

**Report**

Report table contain Supplier Status only.

**Result**

I am trying to get the count according to the supplier status based on the check (expect “NA”) and condition (=X) only from Data table to Report table.

I am trying to count Ok and Not Ok according to the Supplier status (expect “NA”) with condition =X

**Data**

[image]

**Desired Result:**

```js
SUPPLIER STATUS            NOT OK                OK

A1           5              5

A2           4              4

A3           3              3

A4           2              2

A5           1              1

MIXED  1              3
```

```html
CHECK  SUPPLIER STATUS            CONDITION

OK          A1           X

OK          A1           X

OK          A1           X

OK          A1           X

OK          A1           X

NOT OK                A1           X

NOT OK                A1           X

NOT OK                A1           X

NOT OK                A1           X

NOT OK                A1           X

OK          A2           X

OK          A2           X

OK          A2           X

OK          A2           X

NOT OK                A2           X

NOT OK                A2           X

NOT OK                A2           X

NOT OK                A2           X

OK          A3           X

OK          A3           X

OK          A3           X

NOT OK                A3           X

NOT OK                A3           X

NOT OK                A3           X

OK          A4           X

OK          A4           X

NOT OK                A4           X

NOT OK                A4           X

OK          A5           X

NOT OK                A5           X

OK          MIXED  X

OK          MIXED  X

OK          MIXED  X

NOT OK                MIXED  X

OK          NA          NA

OK          NA          NA

OK          NA          NA

NOT OK                NA          NA

NOT OK                NA          NA

NOT OK                NA          NA
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you please advise anyone regarding my query.

Comment: And what solution have you tried so far that is not working? What is the purpose of the report table (and its relationship with Data table)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't tried anything so far. There is a relationship in-between two tables that's called the "Supplier Status". The "supplier status" are available in both tables.

Comment: Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  stackoverflow is not about asking for a solution, but about helping with a problem that you put in an effort to solve, but couldn't find a satisfying solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I search already and I can't found any similar solution that's the reason I posted here. " I haven't tried anything so far" that's means I am trying to crate formula my self".

Comment: I tried something here but it's give a wrong result. It's almost working I need to apply one more filter here which is (Conditions=X). Can you please advise on this.RESULT OK = CALCULATE(COUNT(DATA[SUPPLIER STATUS]),FILTER(ALL(DATA),DATA[SUPPLIER STATUS]=EARLIER(REPORT[SUPPLIER STATUS]) && CALCULATE(COUNT(DATA[CONDITION]),DATA[CHECK]="OK")))

Comment: I achieved my desired my desired result in power Bi visual. Here is link for your reference. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwd5cgy88pi9yd0/SOC.PNG?dl=0 .I would like to achieve the same result by using DAX (New Calculated column). Can you please advise.

Comment: Herewith attached the Power Bi file for your reference. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vaha63abzurzuc/CALCULATE%20and%20count%20based%20on%20the%20three%20different%20columns%28DAX%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually use a measure, not a calculated column. To get a measure filter results like you did in the visual, you need to use the combination of `CALCULATE`/`FILTER` functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-function-dax

`Count = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DATA), FILTER(DATA, DATA[CONDITION] = "X"))`

Drop this measure in the values container of the matrix visual.

You can also have a separate measure for counting OK and NOR OK, like:

`#Not OK = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DATA), FILTER(DATA, DATA[CONDITION] = "X" && DATA[SUPPLIER STATUS] = "NOT OK"))`

`#OK = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DATA), FILTER(DATA, DATA[CONDITION] = "X" && DATA[SUPPLIER STATUS] = "OK"))`